# HTML/JS: Animated collapsible not working. Can you tell me what mistake I have made?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the downward opening motion to be a smooth animation as well as the upward motion.

```js
var arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var arrow_icon = document.getElementById("arrow_icon");

function arrow_click() {
    content.style.display = (content.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    //content.style.visibility = (content.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    //content.style.opacity = (content.style.opacity == '100') ? '0' : '100';
    
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } 
    else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
    
    arrow_icon.className = (arrow_icon.className == "fa fa-angle-down") ? "fa fa-angle-up" : "fa fa-angle-down";
}
```

```css
html{
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

.question_box{
    width:300px;
    border-radius:25px;
    background-color:#9DD36E;
    padding:25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out; /* Opera */
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out; /* Explorer 10 */
}

.question_div{
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.links_div{
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size:25px;
}

.answers_div{
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align:justify;
}

.content{
    display:none;
    //visibility:hidden;
    //opacity:0;
    max-height:0;
}

.arrow{
    margin-top:15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:45px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body><div class="question_box">    
    
    <div class="question_div collapsible">
        What is lorem ipsum?
    </div>
    
    <div id="content" class="content" style="display: none;">
        <div class="links_div">
            1,2,3       </div>
        
        <div class="answers_div">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.       </div>
    </div>

    <div id="arrow" class="arrow" onclick="arrow_click();">
        <i id="arrow_icon" class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </div>
    
</div>  
    
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your code - please use this code for solve problem:

**HTML**
add transition for slow move

```
<div id="content" class="content" style="transition: all 0.3s;">
...
</div>
```

**CSS**
use opacity:0 instead of display:none

```
.content{
    opacity:0;
    max-height:0;
}
```

**JS**
and use this function for change opacity and max-width

```
function arrow_click() {
    content.style.opacity = (content.style.opacity == '100') ? '0' : '100';
    
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
     content.style.maxHeight = 0+'px';
        }
    else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
    
    arrow_icon.className = (arrow_icon.className == "fa fa-angle-down") ? "fa fa-angle-up" : "fa fa-angle-down";
}
```

all of this code is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pad60yzq/